# mathematical model of a pendulum

Tags: trigonometry

Suppose the pendulum string is attached to a point on the ceiling 30 cm from the wall. The weight is moved away from its rest position and released at time t=0. At time t=1.4 sec, it reaches its maximum distance from the wall, 37.4 cm away, and then swings back toward the wall again. At time 2.8 sec, the weight reaches a minimum distance of 23.2 cm from the wall, and then swings away again. 
Assuming that the amplitude of the pendulum's swing decreases exponentially with time, find an equation expressing the amplitude A in terms of time t.

I got A= (37.4-23.2)/2= 7.1, but how do I write A in terms of t?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When the problem says $A$ decreases exponentially with $t$, we are told $A=ae^{-kt}$.  You are given two points on that curve and need to evaluate $a,k$.  Plug them in and solve the two equations.

Comment: No.  You were given two pairs of $A$ and $t$.  You should plug each pair into the equation I gave.  That gives two equations in $a$ and $k$.  Solve them simultaneously.  That gives the equation for $A$ as a function of $t$.

Comment: No. The first has $A=7.4$ because the pivot is $30$ cm from the wall and the pendulum is $37.4$ cm from the wall at maximum extent. This is at t= what?. Then the second point has A=what? at t= what?

Answer (score 1):

You might note that a maximum displacement of the pendulum is **not** the amplitude at the moment the maximum occurs.  Thus if the pendulum's displacement at time $t$ is $y(t) = C e^{-kt} \cos(\omega t)$, so that the amplitude at time $t$ is $C e^{-kt}$, then $\dot{y}(t) = C(-k \cos(\omega t) - \omega \sin(\omega t)) e^{-kt}$.  The displacement is equal to the amplitude when $\cos(\omega t) = 1$, and at such times $\dot{y}(t) = -Ck$, not $0$. 
When $\dot{y}(t) = 0$ you have $- k \cos(\omega t) = \omega \sin(\omega t)$,
i.e. $\tan(\omega t) = -k/\omega$, and at that time the amplitude is $\sec(\omega t) = \sqrt{1 + k^2/\omega^2}$ times the displacement.

Comment: You are right and I missed that.  I think it doesn't matter much if the oscillation is fast compared with the decay because you can ignore the $k\cos$ term compared with the $\omega \sin$ term, which is true here.  Otherwise we have three unknowns and two data points, so probably don't have a unique solution.  I bet the problem setter missed it, too.  Well done.